# Transfer Integer to thousands comma separator and save as ulong

Tags: c#

I recevie a ulong from internet,

and need to add comma, like `7859` to `7,859`

i find a lot of web, but no answer

only have transfer integer to string, like below code

```
int x = 12345871

x.ToString("n0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

and result is correct, but i want to save this format as ulong

can do that? or just save as string?

Comment: A number is just a number. What difference does the thousands separator make? (In some cultures, a comma is actually a *decimal point*, and trying to read this as a numeric value would not only change its meaning entirely, but make it *not* a ulong.)

Comment: Ask yourself this: do you think `int v = 16;` and `int v = 0x10;` do anything different? They are just different ways of representing the same number. The number itself doesn't have a format.

Comment: @BoltClock The comma is the decimal "point" for example in German; the point, in turn, separates blocks of thousands -- what the comma would do in the Anglosaxon culture. In other words, the roles of the two characters are reversed. That's an eternal source of confusion (as are the different orderings of the details of calendar dates, and the different naming of powers of thousand -- a German billion is thousand times as much as an American one). I think everybody should stick to 7 bit ASCII, and as compensation the Americans would adopt the metric system.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers won't have a format unless you convert them to string.

When you need to represent them on screen or who knows where is when you need to format your `ulong` as a string.

If you receive a `long` (i.e. a 64-bit integer, `System.Int64`), you just need to parse it using `ulong.Parse` or `ulong.TryParse`:

```
ulong someLong;
if(ulong.TryParse(longAsText, out someLong))
{
   // Parsing was successful!
}
```